# Traer resultado Json con Java JsonObject

Tags: java, json

tengo un problema con una consulta, resulta que yo consumo un servicio de una base de datos de mongoDB donde la respuesta es un json, en java con esta respuesta necesito validar un dato en este caso "celular", pero sucede lo siguiente, una veces lo trae cuando existe y otras veces no, osea el objeto es decir

```
"celular":{
           "numero":"3000000000"}
```

necesito guardar en una variable el valor, sea que exista o no ese objeto de json, en caso de que exista, se como guardar el numero, pero si no existe me estalla el programa y no se como guardar en caso de que no exista, un espacio vacio o ponerle 0, espero que me puedan ayudar con esto, gracias

Comment: Es necesario saber de qué clase es tu `JSONObject` para poder ayudarte. Hay varias librerías para trabajar con JSON.

Comment: ` import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser; `

Answer (score 3):

Modelo para el mongo

```
 @Document(collection="Nombre_de_tu_colección")
 public class Principal { // se puede llamar como quieras.
    private Data celular; // la clase se puede llamar como quieras, el nombre de la variable como venga del mongo.
    //getter,setter, construcotres etc.... 
 }

public class Data{ // se puede llamar como quieras.
  private String numero; // nombre de la variable como venga del mongo.
  //getter,setter, construcotres etc.... 
}
```

Implementación:

```
   List<Principal> lista = this.repositorio.findAll(); // te traes todos los objetos del mongo
   Principal objeto;
   List<String> resultado = new ArrayList<>();
   for (int i = 0; i <lista.size(); i++) {
    objeto = lista.get(i);
    if(null == objeto.getCelular()){
      resultado.add("El objeto numero:" + i + " ,no tenía datos");
        }else{
          resultado.add("El objeto numero:" + i + " tenía datos: " + objeto.getCelular().getNumero());
         }

       }
```

El problema radica en que en tu JSON, el número está dentro de un objeto. Si no hay datos en el mongo, ese objeto te viene a NULL, entonces NO puedes  hacer `objeto.getCelular().getNumero();`, tienes que comprobarlo primero.